# sql get ordered

Tags: php, sql, arrays

It is easy to explain what i want to perform:

I have a SQL large database, which stores every hour a different value.

ID = represents the record number, auto increment.
data = the data stored.

i get the last 10 values here:

```
"SELECT * FROM myDB order by ID desc LIMIT 10"
```

Next, i use the data to create an array.

```
$dataArray = array(); // make a new array to hold all your data
$index = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
    $dataArray[$index]=$row["profit"];
    $index++;
    }
```

And finally, show the array:

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($dataArray as $key => $val) {
   echo $index." - ".$val."<br>";
   $index++;
}
```

I got this:

0 - 0.37
1 - 0.31
2 - 0.31
3 - 0.31
4 - 0.1
5 - 0.1
6 - 0.1
7 - 0.1
8 - 0.1
9 - 0.1

BUT.. 0.37 is the last value stored in the DB, and i need it as the last value in the array. So, i tried starting from 9 when i assing index and decrease the index variable:

```
$dataArray = array(); // make a new array to hold all your data
$index = 9;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
    $dataArray[$index]=$row["profit"];
    $index--;
    }

$index = 0;
foreach ($dataArray as $key => $val) {
   echo $index." - ".$val."<br>";
   $index++;
}
```

But i got the same result. How can i get the 10 last values of my DB, and put it into an array where the last value of the array is the last value of the DB?

Comment: Start from 9 in your second loop

Comment: `$dataArray = array_reverse($dataArray);` before the `foreach` will do

Comment: It works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In the query itself order it again as asc

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM myDB order by ID desc LIMIT 10) order by ID
```